# Sharepoint View list

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, csom, sharepoint-list

I have several lists in SharePoint, **and each list has a number of views**

**How can I get view list items with value in SharePoint using REST API?**
Can I get this data through CSOM?

**When I use this method, I have this output** :

```
http://win-lfl4bgulf29/_api/lists/getbytitle('EvertList')/views
```

[image: Sharepoint view list output]

**But I'm looking for that**

[image: Sharepoint List]

Comment: check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/136002/8068) link

Comment: @GautamSheth Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Endpoint like below to view list item data:

```
 _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('EvertList')/items"
```

Ajax call like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Cars')/items",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
         console.log(data.d.results);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error");

        }
    });
```

Responsed Json in Console:

[image]